# I'm an HTML beginner and I need help coding static text

Tags: html, css

I'm running a server with Apache and I had a question: You know how on some websites there is somethings that stay in place whenever you scroll?

An example of this is on Facebook where it says 'New Event' and it scrolls down with you when you scroll. I was wondering how to do this. I have WAMP installed on the server computer, so if it needs PHP, I can do that. I wasn't really sure of what to use as a search term for this.

Edit: What is this called so I can do a Google search for it?

Comment: Do you know about CSS at all? If you don't, you kinda need to :)

Comment: use iframe or div style="overflow: scroll;"

Comment: No, I don't know CSS. I'll look up a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for quite some time, I eventually found some code that worked for me. I added a some line breaks at the beginning of my website, then added this CSS code to the head:

```
.navbar {
z-index = 1000;             /*or some large number*/
position: fixed;            /*this makes it scroll down with you*/
width: 100%;                /*the border takes up all the width available*/
height: 40px;               /*and takes up 40 pixels vertically*/
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me with this!

Answer (score 4):

You should google things by how you think of'm, only shorter.

This I would google as "div scroll with screen" or something. It should get you there.

Anyway, You use CSS for this. You make a div (i'm guessing you know what it is) and give it a "fixed" position. (note; you should put these on the sides or something. the bottom and top gives more code)

So your html will be like

```
<div id="scrolldiv">
 your text here 
</div>
```

and your CSS will look like this:

```
#scrolldiv{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position:fixed;
}
```

if you do not know your way around using CSS yet, you can do it like this (although it is not recommended)

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; position:fixed;"> text here </div>
```

Comment: I think your example `<div>` is missing a quotation mark at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position: fixed;` to the CSS.  This tells it to position relative to the browser window, rather than relative to the page.

Answer (score 1):

give your element a class eg

```
<div class='navbar'>
<!-- your menu html goes here -->
</div>
```

In the head of you page put style tags

```
<style>
.navbar {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
</style>
```

also look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ it is a great kick start to this kind of thing. It also features the fixed menu you are talking about in the examples.

I use google chrome and the inspect element features are great for finding the css of an element. Some people also use Firebug with firefox for similar features.